# Internet Explorer Multiple Posts

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have an application that works fine either remotely or locally in the latest Firefox and the latest Opera; never any multiple posts issue.

The issue only arises with Internet Explorer (I've only tested it on 10 and Edge).

Basically If I run the application; the application (MVC) comprises a basic form, some basic client side javascript to verify input, and then submits, which is then stored in the database.

If I run the app over the intranet (using IE) it seemingly randomly posts one or multiple times. It has posted triplicate once, and duplicate around another 10 times, out of around 180 uses of the page.

If I run the application locally (using the same IE browser) on my development machine (localhost) then it never produces multiple posts.

There are no JS errors, no errors at all.

Here is the code for the button in case it is relevent:

```
<button id="btnSubmit"
        style="padding:0;border:none;cursor:pointer;height:30px"
        type="submit"
        disabled>
          <img id="btnSubmitImage" 
               src="~/content/images/bc_ConfirmDisabled.gif"
               alt="Confirm" />
</button>
```

It's got me a bit stumped at the moment.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Tom John for giving the answer which pointed me to the issue... and for future readers here is more information:

The  tag has been a problem for IE for over 13 years!
https://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE

And here W3 Schools says the  tag is not supported in IE https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp

Bloody IE!

So basically I will shortly be replacing all  tags with  in this application, because it is solely used on devices which only house IE 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
type="submit"
```

to

```
type="button"
```

I am pretty sure I've hit this in the past in IE.

Comment: You absolute star!... and now I hate IE even more! It's been a problem for over 13 years! OMFG https://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE and here W3 Schools says the <button> tag is not supported in IE https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp.... OMFG!

Comment: It's now become second nature for me whenever I "handle" a button with JS to change the button type.

Comment: I've decided to just replace them all with <input> , especially since even W3 schools is saying the <button> tag is not supported at all in IE, since i've read about multiple wierd issues with the <button> tag in IE, one where it was posting multiple values, not just the selected one.